# How to get specific password credentials end-date of an application in azure using java

Tags: java, azure

If we have multiple password credentials for an application in azure using java,i am able to get the password credentials by using Object ID. If we have multiple password credentials, is there any way to get the specific password credentials end-date in java.

```
    ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = ApplicationTokenCredentials.fromFile(credFile);
    Azure.Authenticated authenticated = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials);

    String appObjectId = "b48bc188-ff55-4655-a1d0-b8590c179a99";

    ActiveDirectoryApplication application = authenticated.activeDirectoryApplications().getById(appObjectId);

    Map<String, PasswordCredential> map = application.passwordCredentials();

    for ( Map.Entry<String,PasswordCredential> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        PasswordCredential value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Name -> " + key + " ; End date -> " + value.endDate().toString());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
    Name -> 5fc9bb7a-5251-4baa-ar73-928e346ebr54d  ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
    Name-> 3ba9bb7b-5121-6brf-a373-658e346eb44d ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
    Name-> 8f2sr7db-2688-3rfv-a586-591f346eb44d  ; End date -> 2299-12-30T16:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this API to get password credentials of your Azure AD application :

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/<tenant Id>/applications/<app object Id>?api-version=1.6
```

You can find end-date in `passwordCredentials` in its response : 
[image]

There is no way to get a specific password credential by keyId. But I found an API maybe helpful for you that you can filter password credentials by its display name which you configed on Azure portal :

```
GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<app obj id>/passwordCredentials
```

[image]
[image]
This is the [official reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) about this API. Hope it helps.

How to get the API response using java code :

```
String applicationID = "<your app id>";
String applicationPass = "<your app password>";
String tenant = "<your tenant id>" ;
String appObjID = "<app obj id that you want to query >"; 

ExecutorService service = null; 

service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoft.com/" + tenant, false, service); 
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(applicationID, applicationPass);
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = ctx.acquireToken( "https://graph.microsoft.com",clientCredential,null);
String accessToken = future.get().getAccessToken();

URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/"+appObjID+"/passwordCredentials");



 Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url(url)
         .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)  
         .build();

 OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
 try (Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {

     if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

     // Get response body
     System.out.println(response.body().string());
 }
```

Maven dep:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Result :
[image]

Pls note if you want to do this query, make sure your app has the permission below : 
[image]

Comment: Is both the password credentials giving the endDate of Current application credntials or not?

Comment: Yes , you can find both of your app password credentials' endDate  in this API response .

Comment: is there any way to get the application password with the help of password Credentials  keyID?

Comment: Hi @user12061625 , unfortunately ,I am afraid there is no way to get specific password credential by its keyId for now .

Comment: May i know is there any use of 2-3 password credentials for a single application?

Comment: Hi , @user12061625 generally we will use only one password  credentials to do auth process but we can create multiple password  credentials for backup if the one we are using is expired . Or we can use different password credentials in different service and when we want to abandonment certain service , we can just delete the password credential directly in Azure AD App. I found something maybe helpful , and updated my answer , pls have a check.

Comment: Hi, @user12061625, may I know is it helpful ?

Comment: i have tried with your update but i am getting the password credentials object as below: 
i had not find any display name.So i am looking for other possibilities

Comment: Hi @user12061625 are you using this api: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<app obj id>/passwordCredentials' to get your credentials ?

Comment: @user12061625 Hi , updated the code how to get display name

Comment: thanks for your update @Stanley Gong,but we are not using graph API to get the password credentials because we have an issue with permissions. I am using the java code to get the password credentials which i was posted above.

Comment: @user12061625 I am afraid there is no way to get display name or get specific password cred using your code. Anyway good luck .